# Reading a wordpad file with 3 columns in Java

Tags: java

I want to read a text file containing space sepearted values. Values are integers. How can I read it? I want to read each line and after go to next.

The contents are as the example:

> "12/11/2012"          "00.00.01"          0,100
>
> "12/11/2012"          "00.00.05"          0,140
>
> "12/11/2012"          "00.00.09"          0,240
>
> "12/11/2012"          "00.00.13"          0,247

The first column is the date, the second is second and the third is litres.

How can I do it with a Java program?

I think of using Scanner class. I made this program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File text = new File("C:\Users\Desktop\test\test.txt");

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
            lineNumber++;
        }       

    }   

}
```

But I haven't the result that I would like to have.
Any help?

Comment: google "java File IO"

Answer (score 0):

This would be done by simple google search as well.. first you would find code like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class FileRead 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

Replace the System.out.println with some code to get all content from " to " Like:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

        int start = 1, pos = 0,lastpos= 1;
        String dates, times, values;

        if(strLine.indexOf("\"",lastpos) > 0){
            pos = strLine.indexOf("\"",lastpos);
            dates = strLine.substring(start,pos);
            lastpos = pos+3;//replace through search for \"

            pos = strLine.indexOf("\"",lastpos);
            times = strLine.substring(lastpos,pos);
            lastpos = pos+2;//replace through search for \"

            values = strLine.substring(lastpos,strLine.length());


            System.out.println(dates);//Convert to Date
            System.out.println(times);//Convert to time
            System.out.println(values);//Convert to Integer.valueOf/)

            System.out.println("next line");
        }

    }
```

Comment: how i separete each value? I meen how the first would be date, second the seconds and the third the litres?

Comment: shouldn't i have to declare from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest in Java is to use Apache Commons Libraries.
Just add the following dependency in your pom file (if you are using maven)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can do

```
File file = new File("yourFile.txt");
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
```

You will get each of line of your file in the list. Then to get the content of your file:

```
for(String line : lines){
    String[] columns = line.split(" ") //because your columns seem to be separated by a white space
}
```

The array columns will contain your data

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
//column 1
Date date = format.format(column[0]);
//column 2
//I'm not sure to get your second column, is it just second or can it be more?
//column 3
double litres = Double.parseDouble(column[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CSV file. You could use a [CSV tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053761/what-is-a-good-csv-java-utility) to read it.

I know CSV means 'comma separated values', and your file doesn't have commas, but CSV tools can also read files separated by space.